# How to stop toggling star rating on click in ui.bootstrap Star rating?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, rating, uib

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-star', stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart', stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'},
    {stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'},
    {stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'}
  ];
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
    <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<30, 'label-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'label-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>

    <pre style="margin:15px 0;">Rate: <b>{{rate}}</b> - Readonly is: <i>{{isReadonly}}</i> - Hovering over: <b>{{overStar || "none"}}</b></pre>

    

    
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

> I have the above code snippet where if I select 3 stars and again
>   click back on the 3rd star, rating becomes 0. This means click toggles rating value. I don't want the rating value
>   to toggle anyway. Couldn't find any proper way. Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [**`uib-rating`** | Angular-UI docs](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#rating), it has an attribute

> **`enable-reset`**: (Default: `true`) - Clicking the icon of the current rating will reset the rating to `0`.

Just set that to `false` and you are good to go! Here's working example!

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('RatingDemoCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rate = 7;
  $scope.max = 10;
  $scope.isReadonly = false;

  $scope.hoveringOver = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
  };

  $scope.ratingStates = [{
      stateOn: 'glyphicon-ok-sign',
      stateOff: 'glyphicon-ok-circle'
    },
    {
      stateOn: 'glyphicon-star',
      stateOff: 'glyphicon-star-empty'
    },
    {
      stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart',
      stateOff: 'glyphicon-ban-circle'
    },
    {
      stateOn: 'glyphicon-heart'
    },
    {
      stateOff: 'glyphicon-off'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div ng-controller="RatingDemoCtrl">
    <h4>Default</h4>
    <span uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max" enable-reset="false" read-only="isReadonly" on-hover="hoveringOver(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></span>
    <span class="label" ng-class="{'label-warning': percent<30, 'label-info': percent>=30 && percent<70, 'label-success': percent>=70}" ng-show="overStar && !isReadonly">{{percent}}%</span>

    <pre style="margin:15px 0;">Rate: <b>{{rate}}</b> - Readonly is: <i>{{isReadonly}}</i> - Hovering over: <b>{{overStar || "none"}}</b></pre>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```